# Searching in a Boost Asio Buffer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a boost buffer and I'm going to search something inside this buffer, something like this code:

```
auto buffer = boost::asio::buffer(my_array, my_array_size);
if (buffer.find("Hello"))
  cout << "Found";
else
  cout << "Not Found";
```

I know that the `find` function doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you get the underlying raw buffer? If yes, consider std::search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the content and use `std::search` to know whether such a sequence exists or not.

```
std::size_t size = boost::asio::buffer_size(buffer);
unsigned char* data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<unsigned char*>(buffer);
unsigned char pattern[] = {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'};

auto it = std::search(data, data + size, std::begin(pattern), std::end(pattern));

if (it != data + size){
    cout << "found";
} else {
    cout << "not found";
}
```

Note that since we're dealing with raw memory bytes, you should take care of encoding when searching strings inside the buffer.